# Microsoft Edge false support of AV1 on canPlayType

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, microsoft-edge, chromium

Microsoft Edge 85 has a false positive indication of an AV1 video codec support.

Checking like this returns "probably" which usually indicates that video codec is safe to use.

```
videoElement.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="av01.0.05M.08"')
```

Putting AV1 source element causes Edge to pick AV1 over other codecs and fail to play it.

```
<video playsinline loop autoplay muted>
    <source type="video/webm; codecs='av01.0.05M.08'" src="av1.webm">
    <source type="video/webm; codecs='vp9'" src="vp9.webm">
    <source type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.64001f'" src="avc.mp4">
</video>
```

Is there any other way to detect codec support more effectively with no false positives as mentioned above?

Comment: I try to check for the issue with the MS Edge 85 and other browsers. This is my [test code](https://justpaste.it/230hi). I can able to produce the issue with the MS Edge 85 browser. I also try to directly play the video in the Edge browser but it also did not get played whereas it works fine in the Chrome browser. I try to find whether this is a known issue but did not get information on it. I suggest you press ALT + SHIFT + I key in the MS Edge browser and try to provide your feedback regarding this issue to Microsoft. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Microsoft Edge 85 and earlier officially doesn't support AV1 videos. The issue is not even in the fact that it doesn't play it (while the same version of Chrome does), but that the browser picks the format from source elements and indicates with canPlayType like if it could play it.

Comment: Thanks for providing more information about the issue. We are aware of the issue. As a current workaround, I suggest you try to identify the Edge browser using your JS code and inform the users that MS Edge currently does not supports the AV1 codec. Further, you can also try to assign the supported codec and source dynamically for the Edge browser. It may help to avoid the issue temporarily.

Comment: I tried it on Microsoft Edge 86 beta and 87 dev as well. Sadly, the same situation remains with newer builds of the browser. Identifying a browser to avoid such a bug is a dirty solution that I would love to avoid, but looks like there is no other option.

Comment: As of May 2021, the issue still remains

Comment: As of May 2022, the issue still remains

Comment: As of June 2022, the issue still remains.............

Comment: End of 2023 and Edge 119 — still same issue. @Deepak-MSFT is there a tracking issue for this bug we can follow?

Comment: Also still having this issue. I'd hope that Microsoft would, at least, drop support for AV1 temporarily, so the alternative video sources would be picked by Edge instead, until they properly fix AV1.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice from @Deepak-MSFT and use JS to replace the video source on Edge.

I've confirmed that this works in Edge 103 on Window 10 21H2.
The browser will still make a request for the unplayable AV1 WebM file, but will then switch over and play the AVC MP4 file.

```js
// Target Edge on Windows with UserAgent and Platform strings
if (
  window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes("edg") &&
  window.navigator.platform === "Win32"
) {
  // Select the video element
  const video = document.querySelector("video");
  
  // Select the playable source file and set video src
  video.src = video
    .querySelector("source[type='video/mp4']")
    .getAttribute("src");
}
```

This assumes that you have only one source element with `type="video/mp4"`. The query selector could be more specific, e.g. select for `codecs` attribute, to target a very specific source. Another option is to add `id` attributes to your source elements and target the desired source that way.